# Apex. Calling proc within htp.prn?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'd like to know, how to call proc under the button in APEX.
Here are the steps perform by me:
-adding blank page in application
-adding button exp. bellow the region
-adding Dynamic action PL/SQL for button
-choosing Action like Execute PL/SQL
-adding PL/SQL code below

PL/SQL code:

```
BEGIN
WYCEN_POJAZD('Audi', 'A4', 2013, 'DIESEL', 2000)
END;
```

PL/SQL procedure i'm talking about:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE WYCEN_POJAZD
(
 p_marka IN BAZA_EUROTAX.MARKA%TYPE,
 p_model IN BAZA_EUROTAX.MODEL%TYPE,
 p_rok_prod IN BAZA_EUROTAX.ROK_PRODUKCJI%TYPE,
 p_paliwo IN BAZA_EUROTAX.RODZAJ_PALIWA%TYPE,
 p_pojemnosc IN BAZA_EUROTAX.POJEMNOSC%TYPE
)
IS
 ex_wycena BAZA_EUROTAX.WYCENA%TYPE;
BEGIN
 SELECT WYCENA INTO ex_wycena
 FROM BAZA_EUROTAX
 WHERE MARKA = p_marka
       AND MODEL = p_model
       AND ROK_PRODUKCJI = p_rok_prod
       AND RODZAJ_PALIWA = p_paliwo
       AND POJEMNOSC = p_pojemnosc;
IF ex_wycena > 0
   THEN
     htp.prn('WYCENA KATALOGU EUROTAX' || <br > ||
                          'Twój pojazd został wyceniony na: ' || ex_wycena ||
                          ' PLN.'); 
END IF;
 EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
   htp.prn('Wprowadzony pojazd nie został znaleziony w bazie EUROTAX. W trakcie zawierania ubezpieczenia, prosimy
                        o powołanie się na wartość pojazdu jaka została zapisana na dokumencie potwierdzającym nabycie pojazdu.' || <br > ||
                        'DZIĘKUJEMY!');
END WYCEN_POJAZD;
```

PROC is written under polish user.

htp.p - it's not working too.

Thanks a lot for helping me get through APEX. I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling htp.prn simply assign this value to apex_application.g_print_success_message. After this your message will be shown in next page in default success box.